# Do I need to repeat the WHERE clause in a 'IN (SELECT MAX(id)' subquery?

Tags: mysql, subquery

Do I need to specify the WHERE clause inside this subquery as well?

```
SELECT title, message FROM messages WHERE sender = '.$myid.' AND read != 1 AND id
IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM messages GROUP BY conversation) ORDER BY id DESC
```

It seems like the result is the same with/without repeating the WHERE clause, but it's hard to test without having a lot of different users and messages. So I need to be more sure.

Is it necessary to repeat the WHERE clause like this , or is the IN subquery already narrowed down by the first WHERE clause? (I assume the latter but I'm not sure).

```
SELECT title, message FROM messages WHERE sender = '.$myid.' AND read != 1 AND id
IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM messages WHERE sender = '.$myid.' AND read != 1 GROUP BY conversation) ORDER BY id DESC
```

Both are simplified examples from my code. I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: Sure, the where in the subquery is required but the ones in the outer query aren't really needed as you are requesting exact ids using your subquery

Comment: @ahmad You mean I could/should do it like this? `SELECT title, message FROM messages WHERE id
IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM messages WHERE sender = '.$myid.' AND read != 1 GROUP BY conversation) ORDER BY id DESC`

Comment: Yes, exactly the ones in the outside aren't really doing anything as you are doing the same in the subquery.

Comment: Ok I just tested that, and I got the same result (it works as well). This is a bit over my head, so I guess I'll have to trust that the WHERE clause is enough in the subquery as you say. I need to understand it better and test it some more

Comment: You should post an answer, perhaps with some explanation if you have it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The where in the outer query is redundant as in your inner query (subquery) you are requesting specific ids using the constraint you want so basically when you have something like this:

```
SELECT title, message FROM messages WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM messages WHERE
sender = '.$myid.' AND read != 1 GROUP BY conversation) ORDER BY id DESC
```

it would be like you have gathered the ids first & then requested the specific records similar to: `select x from y where id in(1, 2, 3)`

For this same exact query it would be like running the following 2 queries:

```
Query 1: SELECT MAX(id) FROM messages WHERE sender = '.$myid.' AND read != 1 GROUP BY conversation

Result: 1, 2, 3
```

The second query is:

```
Query 2: SELECT title, message FROM messages WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3) ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The sub query select is completely separate to the first in terms of arguments parsed, so you will have to enter the where clause information again